# Automatically update field in current row of an observablearray from textInput field

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a table bound to a view model. When I select the table row, a field (notes) is updated from this:

```html
<tbody data-bind="foreach: namespace.PersonResults.model">
    <tr data-bind="click: $root.selectItem, css: {selected: $root.isSelected($data)}">
        <td data-bind="text: Forename"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Surname"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: PostCode"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Notes" style="display: none"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The field in the same div as the table (this is a single text area that should be updated when selecting the row on the table above, and update the table by the time the user chooses another row).

```html
<textarea data-bind="textInput: editNotes"></textarea>
```

the viewModel is currently doing this:

```
var resultsViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.model = ko.observableArray();
    self.editNotes = ko.observable();

    self.selectItem = function(record) {
    self.selectedItem(record);
        self.editNotes(record.Notes);
    }

    self.getData () {
        // some ajax stuff to populate the table
    }
}
```

This works fine for displaying the notes in the `textarea`, but how do I get this to go the other way, and populate the field in the `observableArray` if the user has altered the contents of the `textarea`?

Comment: Please add how you're including that `textarea` in your view; help us reproduce your problem.

Comment: aha I see what I did, I forgot to add the snippet for the textarea.

Comment: actually the way I'd added the snippet for the textarea meant it didnt show in the final question. fixed.

Comment: Makes a bit more sense now. Why do you bind your `td` with `Notes` instead of `editNotes`? (As another side note, it'd help if you extend your code even a little further, so that it is a direct repro of your situation...)

Comment: Ok, have added a closer approximation to my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just bind a `td` to the same property as the `textarea`. E.g.:

```js
var resultsViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.editNotes = ko.observable('initial value');
}

var vm = { 
  selectedResult: ko.observable(null),
  results: [new resultsViewModel(), new resultsViewModel()] 
};

vm.selectResult = function(result) { vm.selectedResult(result); };

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
.selected { background-color: pink; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table><tbody data-bind="foreach: results">
    <tr data-bind="css: { selected: $root.selectedResult() === $data }">
        <td data-bind="text: editNotes"></td>
        <td><button data-bind="click: $root.selectResult">Select</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>

<!-- ko with: selectedResult -->
<textarea data-bind="textInput: editNotes"></textarea>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: yes, but then I end up with two text areas. the text area is supposed to update when the user selects the row.

Comment: @JimFR Could be, but you should really consider updating your question to reflect that. You should check [this help center guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); had you followed it someone would've probably answered your question definitively within 5 minutes of posting... (In any case, my answer's updated.)

Comment: fair point, well made! I tend to be a bit too concise, yet waffly sometimes! :-p

Comment: This is now almost exactly what I want! I'll test it, then mark it as accepted in a bit :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind to the `value` of a `textarea`:

```
<td>
      <textArea data-bind="value: $data.Notes"></textArea>
</td>
```

I've knocked up a quick and simplified demo in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjoe3t4b/)

Edited to add:

Here's an updated fiddle that's more in line with what you want: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjoe3t4b/3/)